# Linux shell commands execution

Tags: linux, command, alias, execution

From terminal i need execute a command like this :

```
test /home/root/myimg.jpg
```

where test is an executable file and myimg.jpg is an image that i pass to exe file.

The image is, in may case, the last file added to the /home/root directory and i can see it from terminal by typing `ls /home/root | tail -n 1`.

i need to write an alias that allows me to pass the latest image saved in the directory. How can i do it ? Because is ever the last image added that i need to pass and its name changes everytime !!!

thanks a lot for every answer :)

Comment: Beware that `test` is some *existing* command and often a shell builtin. Name your executable something else, e.g. `andreastest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias name='test $(ls /home/root | tail -n 1.)'
```

should do the job.
Explanation:
$(command) replaces itself with the output of command

Comment: i've just tried both solutions proposed and doesn't works :(

Comment: to be more precise, in the source code of the exe file there is the instruction img=imread(argv[1]). The funcion entry is the image that i pass to the exe with the command test  /home/root/myimg.jpg

Comment: What shell are jou using ? you can find that out with "echo $SHELL"

Comment: i'm using Yocto..that is linux based...and however, when i type echo $SHELL it says to me " /bin/sh "

Comment: Weird that  should work in sh. Is there an error message , if Yes what does it say

Comment: There is the error message that the code that i written says when the image cannot be loaded..but there is no shell command error

Comment: Try echo $(ls /home/root | tail -n 1) does it show the correct file name ?

Comment: try test /home/root/$(ls /home/root | tail -n 1) maybe the script just looks in the wrong Directory

Comment: Yesssss, it works !!!! Thank a lot for your answer and the time spent, Cyljus !!!!

Comment: Neat ! the script was probably just in a diffrent folder and was looking for the file in its directory